# What do you call it when you pass a parameter to the next parameter

Tags: c#, javascript

I notice a lot of code where people do something like:

```
myClass.someMethod(something here, $1);
```

The $1 is picking up a value from "something here"?

What is this known as? I can't seem to find it anywhere? But this step, process is used in cases with regex quite a bit..

Comment: what *concrete* language you're talking about ?

Comment: You're going to need to provide a specific example from actual code.

Comment: Pick a language.  This will have different meanings for different languages.

Comment: I can't see I've ever seen this construct used before. It's certainly not something that I am aware of in C#.

Comment: where have you noticed that lot of code?

Comment: Sorry the question was very generic, wanted to target a range of people. For my own greedy purposes I succeeded. @Jonathan Sampson gave me exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Annath http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.aspx

Comment: @AlexFilipovici `navigation.replace(/<span[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/span>/g, "$1");` in javascript

Comment: @John Dibling I was aiming at C# and Javascript sorry.

Comment: @Nambari  I was aiming at C# and Javascript sorry.

Comment: @Pointy navigation.replace(/<span[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/span>/g, "$1"); in javascript

Comment: Anicho, you might notice that "$1" is **quoted** and thus appears within a string in most of the Javascript replace examples.

Comment: @Tigran C# and/or Javascript is what I am aiming for. Sorry

Comment: @Paul debugging it doing what Johnathan Sampson has suggested.

Comment: @Anicho Right, I assumed you were talking about a language feature/syntactical construct and not a regex. Failure of communication I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll often see this in regular expressions where `$1` represents a *capture group* that you're carrying over into the new value.

For example, suppose we're building a tweet-parser for our website. We want to find @ references in the tweet, and convert them into links to those particular accounts:

```
// Our Tweet
$t = "I am @jonathansampson, and I work with @appendTo.";

// Find every occurence of @something, capture 'something'
echo preg_replace("/@([a-z]+)/i", "<a href='http://twitter.com/$1'>$0</a>", $t);
```

Note here that we're matching every occurrence of @something, but we're wrapping the username portion in `(` and `)` so that we can handle it individually in our replacement text. The entire pattern is represented by `$0`, which will hold the value in its entirety from `@` to the last char in the username.

The same is true for JavaScript:

```
var tweet = "I am @jonathansampson, and I work with @appendTo.",
    patrn = /@([a-z]+)/gi,
    links = tweet.replace(patrn, "<a href='http://twitter.com/$1'>$&</a>");
```

The variable `links` now contains the value:

```
console.log(links);
/*
    "I am <a href='http://twitter.com/jonathansampson'>@jonathansampson</a>, and 
     I work with <a href='http://twitter.com/appendTo'>@appendTo</a>."
*/
```

You might note that I used `$&` in JavaScript to grab the entire matched pattern while using `$0` in PHP - we have to deal with these differences in life. My apologies ;)

Comment: see also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace Look for "Example: switching words in a string"

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson Thank you, and apologies for not being so clear in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about javascript, $ can be used in declarations, so it could be a few things.

For example you could declare a variable as

```
var $1 = 1;
```

Then use it in your call

```
myClass.someMethod(something here, $1);
```

Equally it could be a reference to a function.